# Python Flask and Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, flask

I am trying to upload a CSV file, and read it with Pandas, then add a column of data to that CSV file. But, I'm getting an error pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

```
@app.route("/success", methods=["POST"])
def success():
    global file
    if request.method=="POST":
        file=request.files["file"]
        file.save(secure_filename("uplodovano"+file.filename))
        podaci=pd.read_csv(file, index_col="Rbr")
        df=pd.DataFrame(podaci)

        while True:
            try:
                if "Adresa" in df.columns:
                    df1=df["Adresa"]
                    lst=[]
                    for i in df1:
                        g1=geocoder.google(i)
                        g2=g1.latlng
                        lst.append(g2)

                    df["Koordinate"]=lst
                    df.to_csv("izvezeno.csv")
                    print(df)
                    break
                elif "adresa" in df.columns:
                    df1=df["adresa"]
                    lst=[]
                    for i in df1:
                        g1=geocoder.google(i)
                        g2=g1.latlng
                        lst.append(g2)

                    df["Koordinate"]=lst
                    df.to_csv("izvezeno.csv")
                    print(df)
                    break
                else:
                    print("Ne postoje podaci o adresama. Please check CSV fajl!!!!!!")
                    break
            except KeyError:
                break
        return render_template("index.html", btn="download.html")@app.route("/success", methods=["POST"])
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're passing the created filename to `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: For example: `pd.read_csv("uplodovano"+file.filename)`